Problema para crear y leer ficheros en Kivy
Estoy haciendo una app en Kivy para mi móvil (Android 13), y estoy interesado en crear y leer ficheros .txt donde se almacenan datos de una lista. La idea es que cuando se abra la app en el móvil se cree automáticamente un fichero .txt y se actualice cada tiempo, y aparte tener la opción de leer ficheros aparte. Esta parte la tengo resuelta cuando compilo en pc, pero para android parece que tengo que especificar permisos concretos que no domino.
De momento tengo esto:
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
# from kivy.utils import platform
import os
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import time
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
import platform

class TotalLimit(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, app, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = dp(50)
        self.app = app

        # Spending Limit
        self.limitLabel = Label(text='Gasto Límite', size_hint=(0.3, None), height=dp(40), font_size=sp(18))
        self.limitInput = TextInput(hint_text='Límite', multiline=False, input_filter='float', size_hint=(0.4, None), height=dp(40), font_size=sp(18))
        self.limitInput.bind(text=app.updateTotal)

        # Total Spent
        self.totalLabel = Label(text='Total: 0', size_hint=(0.3, None), height=dp(40), font_size=sp(18))

        # Add widgets to build list
        self.add_widget(self.limitLabel)
        self.add_widget(self.limitInput)
        self.add_widget(self.totalLabel)

# Main class for the app
class ShoppingListApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Total limit BoxLayout. Add to build
        self.totalLimit = TotalLimit(self)
        self.root.add_widget(self.totalLimit)

        # Build the screen
        self.scrollView = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.listLayout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=dp(10), size_hint_y=None)
        self.listLayout.bind(minimum_height=self.listLayout.setter('height'))
        self.scrollView.add_widget(self.listLayout)
        self.root.add_widget(self.scrollView)

        # Build the buttons
        self.buttonBox = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height=dp(60))
        self.addItemButton = Button(text='Añadir', on_release=self.addItemFunction, size_hint_x=0.5, font_size=sp(18))
        self.clearAllButton = Button(text='Borrar todo', on_release=self.clearAllFunction, size_hint_x=0.5, font_size=sp(18))
        self.loadButton = Button(text='Abrir lista', on_release=self.loadFunction, size_hint_x=0.5, font_size=sp(18))
        self.buttonBox.add_widget(self.addItemButton)
        self.buttonBox.add_widget(self.clearAllButton)
        self.buttonBox.add_widget(self.loadButton)
        self.root.add_widget(self.buttonBox)

        # Call the update function
        self.updateTotal()
        
        # Create list_file.txt at starting app
        if platform.system() == 'Android':
            self.request_android_permissions()
        else:
            self.create_file_on_start()
        
        # Call the dinamic saving thread
        self.savingThreadStart()

        return self.root

    def addItemFunction(self, instance):
        '''Add item to the main list'''
        item = ShoppingListItem(self, removeCallback=self.removeItemFunction)
        self.listLayout.add_widget(item)
        self.updateTotal()

    def removeItemFunction(self, instance):
        '''Remove selected item'''
        self.listLayout.remove_widget(instance.parent)
        self.updateTotal()

    def clearAllFunction(self, instance):
        '''Clear all items function'''
        self.listLayout.clear_widgets()
        self.updateTotal()
        
    def loadFunction(self, instance):
        ''' Function to load list in phone '''
        self.loadWindow = FileChooserPopup(self, self.path, removeCallback=self.removeItemFunction)
        self.loadWindow.open()        

    def updateTotal(self, *args):
        '''Update the main screen'''
        total = sum(
            round(float(child.priceInput.text) * float(child.unitsInput.text), 2)
            for child in self.listLayout.children
            if isinstance(child, ShoppingListItem) and child.priceInput.text != ''
        )
        limit = float(self.totalLimit.limitInput.text) if self.totalLimit.limitInput.text else 0
        self.totalLimit.totalLabel.text = f'Total: {total}'
        self.totalLimit.limitLabel.text = 'Gasto Límite'
        self.totalLimit.limitLabel.color = (0, 0, 0, 1)

        # Change the totalLabel color to red if spent over the limit
        if total > limit:
            self.totalLimit.totalLabel.color = (1, 0, 0, 1)  # Red color
        else:
            self.totalLimit.totalLabel.color = (0, 0, 0, 1)  # Black color
            
    def request_android_permissions(self):
        ''' Request Android permissions to create recipe list at start '''
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], self.permission_callback)
            
    def permission_callback(self, permissions, results):
        # Check if we have Android Permisssions
        if all(results):
            self.create_file_on_start()
            
    def create_file_on_start(self):
        ''' Create list_file.txt, and drectory if is not created '''
        self.path = self.get_storage_path()
        if not os.path.exists(self.path):
            os.makedirs(self.path)

        self.fileName = "List_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + ".txt"
        self.filePath = os.path.join(self.path, self.fileName)
        
        self.date = datetime.now()
        
    def get_storage_path(self):
        ''' Get storage path of android device '''
        if platform.system() == 'Android':
            from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
            return os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(), 'Android', 'media', 'com.shoppinglistapp', 'recipes')
        else:
            return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'ShoppingList_recipes')
        
    # Saving Thread
    def savingThreadStart(self):
        ''' Create the dinamic saving thread '''
        self.stopThread = threading.Event()
        self.saveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.dinamicSave)
        self.saveThread.start()
        
    def dinamicSave(self):
        ''' Thread for dinamic saving of shopping list items '''
        while not self.stopThread.is_set():            
            itemsData = [(child.itemCheck.active, child.nameInput.text, child.priceInput.text, child.unitsInput.text)
                          for child in self.listLayout.children
                          if isinstance(child, ShoppingListItem)
                          and (child.nameInput.text != '' or child.priceInput.text != '')]
            with open(self.filePath, 'w') as file:
                file.write('')
                file.write("Lista guardada el: {}\n".format(self.date) + "\n")
                file.write("Gasto Limite: " + self.totalLimit.limitInput.text + "\n")
                for item in itemsData:
                    file.write(f"{item[0]}, {item[1]}, {item[2]}, {item[3]}\n")
            time.sleep(5)
                
    def on_stop(self):
        ''' Ends the thread safely '''
        self.stopThread.set()
        self.saveThread.join()

# App exe
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)  # White screen background
    ShoppingListApp().run()

He quitado algunas clases que no son relevantes. La duda la tengo con la función
request_android_permissions, permission_callback y get_storage_path.
Esta estructura parece que solo funciona para Android 10-. Para versiones superiores no se adaptarlo.
Mi fichero buildozer.spec tiene los cambios
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt
# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy
# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 34

De nuevo, he quitado elementos del fichero que no son relevantes.
Aquí el problema es que según foros y tal, la estructura que tengo del código es correcta para dispositivos Android 10 o inferior, y no se como adaptarlo para que funcione para mi dispositivo Android 13.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos.
